# PDO search database using LIKE

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am trying to make a small search function to look at database using this code:

```
$searchQ = 'Li';
$query = $connDB->prepare('SELECT * FROM topic WHERE topic_name LIKE '."':keywords'");
$query->bindValue('keywords', '%' . $searchQ . '%');
$query->execute();  

if (!$query->rowCount() == 0) {
    while ($results = $query->fetch()) {
        echo $results['topic_name'] . "<br />\n";
    }
} else {
    echo 'Nothing found';
}
```

This return all of the items in database, not just the ones that are alike,

I then ran this SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM topic WHERE topic_name LIKE '%Li%';
```

and this ran as expected and returned the required result.

What am I missing?

Comment: Not an answer, but worth mentioning that `LIKE` queries with a leading `%` are *extremely* inefficient. The DB has to read the entire table to get the results. If you have (or expect to have) a large number of records in your table, you need to find an alternative way doing this query.

Comment: @Spudley - What method do you recommend?

Comment: there are various options depending on your needs. Easy option: simply use tagging; ie a separate table with keywords. Then there's a `FULLTEXT` index and a `MATCHES` query; flawed, but workable. More complex: a DB search tool like Sphinx: blisteringly fast, but can be a pain to configure.

Comment: there's other options too, and frankly if it's a small table (<1000 records), then even `LIKE` can be "good enough". It's just something to be aware of.

Comment: For other options for full text search see my presentation [Full Text Search Throwdown](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/practical-full-text-search-with-my-sql).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Remove the quotes from the placeholder and add a colon before your bind reference:

```
$query = $connDB->prepare('SELECT * FROM topic WHERE topic_name LIKE :keywords');
$query->bindValue(':keywords', '%' . $searchQ . '%');
```

Here's my text example:

### SQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;


INSERT INTO `items` (`id`, `name`) VALUES
(1, 'apple'),
(2, 'orange'),
(3, 'grape'),
(4, 'carrot'),
(5, 'brick');
```

### PHP

```
$keyword='ap';
$sql="SELECT * FROM `items` WHERE `name` LIKE :keyword;";
$q=$dbh->prepare($sql);
$q->bindValue(':keyword','%'.$keyword.'%');
$q->execute();
while ($r=$q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo"<pre>".print_r($r,true)."</pre>";
}
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [name] => apple
)
Array
(
    [id] => 3
    [name] => grape
)
```

Comment: This still returns all of the content from the DB

Comment: Possible to provide the contents of your db table?

Comment: right now its place holders like: a red apple, a purple grape, a orange orange, a yellow banana. When i run it, it return all items.

Comment: Make suer that `$searchQ` has an actual value.  If you're getting everything back, it's likely that the variable is empty or so generic that everything matches the search criteria.

Comment: Yes, what is the output when you `var_dump($searchQ)`?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't know of a PHP/MySQL/PDO sandbox to show an example. But I've added my example to my answer.

Comment: OK I used the code form that example and modified it to my context and it works, I have no clue, but i will mark yours as correct as it was the one that helped. Thank You!

Comment: Is it secure against SQL injections?

Comment: @PascalGoldbach That depends. You might find this post informative: [Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134099/are-pdo-prepared-statements-sufficient-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a single variable to  `bind_param` not a `concatenated` string, because parameter `two` must be a reference not a value.

```
$keyword_to_search = '%' . $searchQ . '%';
$query->bindValue('keywords', $keyword_to_search);
```

Comment: But the OP is using `bindValue`, not `bindParam`. A concatenated string works for me... is there any documentation that it shouldn't?

Comment: Ok I did that, but still no luck, It still returns all of the contents of the DB

Answer (score -1):

You can only bind data literals.
Try

```
 $searchQ = '%Li%'; OR  $searchQ = '%'.Li.'%';
$query = $connDB->prepare('SELECT * FROM topic WHERE topic_name LIKE :keywords');
$query->bindValue('keywords', $searchQ );
```

Answer (score -1):

## showdev thanks you tutorial

**SQL**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS 'news' 
(`id` int(9) NOT NULL auto_increment, 
  `title` text NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) 
ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
insert into `items` (`id`, `title`) VALUES
(1, 'news title'),
(2, 'news title 2');
```

**PHP**

```
$connection = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME','root','');
if (isset($_GET['store'])) {
$store = $_GET['store'];
if(!empty($store)){//condition you the remove karakter
    $q=$connection->prepare("SELECT title FROM tbl_nes WHERE title LIKE :store");
    $q->bindValue(':store','%'.$store.'%'); 
    $q->execute();
    while ($r = $q->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
        echo $r->title,"<br>";
    }         
}
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
1.news title
2.news title 2 ....
```